# Which way better to store data for cordova applications

Tags: cordova, local-storage, web-sql

In my `cordova` application, I want to hold list of `jsons`. Regarding this which way is better to implement either `localstorage` or `websql`.

If I hold `jsons`, I can show to user as a history,so user can load that data from history list.

can anyone suggest me.

Comment: Localstorage is not async... Better websql.

Comment: @malcubierre but most of the guys saying, `websql` was depricated.

Comment: Yes, But you don't have put indexeddb as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is to use IndexedDB with a shim that calls back to websql if indexeddb is not present

http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/

http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb

If you have huge amount of data (>5MB) only way is through plugins that is based on sqlite native:

https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin